# LoadError: incompatible library version, when deploying with capistrano to Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run cap staging deploy, I get the error

```
LoadError: incompatible library version - /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack/ms…
```

Assets won't precompile when deploying with capistrano to production on Amazon EC2. But I didn't find any solution there.

```
00:42 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 rake aborted!
      01 LoadError: incompatible library version - /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack/ms…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <to…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_g…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (requir…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/boot.rb:6:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/application.rb:3:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/Rakefile:6:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
      01 /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
      01
      01 Caused by:
      01 LoadError: cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <to…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_g…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (requir…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/boot.rb:6:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/application.rb:3:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/Rakefile:6:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
      01 /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
      01
      01 Caused by:
      01 LoadError: incompatible library version - /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack/ms…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <to…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (requir…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/boot.rb:6:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/application.rb:3:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/Rakefile:6:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
      01 /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
      01
      01 Caused by:
      01 LoadError: cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.10/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <to…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (requir…
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/boot.rb:6:in `require'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/application.rb:3:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/Rakefile:6:in `require_relative'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/releases/20190514174408/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /var/www/dbname_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
      01 /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
      01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
#<Thread:0x00005581529e8788@/home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  13: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
  12: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
  11: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
  10: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
   9: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:89:in `within'
   8: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:68:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
   7: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:97:in `with'
   6: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capistrano-rails-1.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:69:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
   5: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:78:in `execute'
   4: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `create_command_and_execute'
   3: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `tap'
   2: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
   1: from /home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:169:in `execute_command'
/home/compname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/command.rb:99:in `exit_status=': rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
```

Comment: Are you developing on windows? It used to not honour the gemfile.lock resulting in different gem versions on server vs development machine.

Comment: Am on Ubuntu 19.04